# Force resolution of xsl:include, xsl:import in Java

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I'm using Saxon 9.3 HE and Java 1.6. I can resolve `xsl:include` and `xsl:import` statements in the xsl by supplying a resolver to `setURIResolver` on the `TransformerFactory` instance.

However the `Source resolve(String includee, String includer)` method doesn't get called if the file was resolved previously. This is a problem for me because I want to resolve differently based on the `includer` file. For example `<xsl:include href="foo.xsl"/>` in `file1.xsl` would be a different file from `<xsl:include href="foo.xsl"/>` in `file2.xsl`, and `file1.xsl` and `file2.xsl` would be included by `file3.xsl`. I have some "base" code and "customer-specific" code that can override the template file and I need to resolve them differently for a framework I'm building.

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT specification is clear that resolving a relative URI in the href attribute against the base URI of the containing element must be done according to the standard rules for handling relative URIs, while dereferencing the resulting absolute URI can be done any way the implementation likes. I'd suggest rethinking your design to take account of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected that because the two XSLs that have that includes in them have different base URIs that the URIResolver would need to be called for each one (what if they are in different directories?).

When creating sources for file1.xsl and file2.xsl, what are their system IDs?  If they are null, exist in the same directory or don't have any path information (i.e. systemId is just `file1.xsl` and `file2.xsl`) maybe Saxon is trying to do an optimization by assuming they are in the same directory and therefore assuming `foo.xsl` referred to by each one is the same file.

Maybe try explicitly [setting the systemId](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Source.html#setSystemId%28java.lang.String%29) of the source of the base files and make them have different directories?